# Safe Bash line continuation

Tags: bash

Line continuation in bash with `\` doesn't work if there is a space after the `\`. This has often resulted in hard to spot bugs in my code.

Also, it prevents me from putting a comment at the end of the line.

Is there a safer way to do line-continuations?

**Update:** The suggestions in the comments are about making the editor detect the trailing whitespaces. This is a valid approach. But is there a way that doesn't depend on the trailing whitespaces to be so significant?

Comment: If your editor can be configured to show trailing whitespace, do so. Vim does this with `set listchars=trail:.` and `set list`. (Check the docs on `listchars`, you can make it hightlight things like tabs and non-breaking spaces as well.) Also, `sed -i "s/\s\+$//" <filename>` makes trailing space go away. Another idea would be a pre-commit-hook implemented in your version control that stubbornly refuses to allow files with trailing whitespace being checked in.

Comment: Or you can set you editor to always strip trailing whitespace. I have had this as a default setting in my editor for at least 6 years and it's never been the wrong thing to do for me.

Comment: Except in Markdown, where trailing spaces can denote a newline within a paragraph. Odd, but it's there!

Comment: paste your code into www.shellcheck.net, it will find them: https://imgur.com/a/Xyq25QK

Comment: If you chain commands with pipes (`|`), the pipe character can be used as the last character on a line, and you can also have comments after it.

Comment: Well `\[space]` is an escaped `[space]`, really just a `[space]`. It's not an escaped newline.... i.e. continued line. So bash is right. I understand it's not what you wanted, I'd still go with no trailing newlines policy in general. Solves problem with `\ ` with obfuscated meaning.