# Using bash for looping through temporary sequence file names and performing FastQC analysis

Tags: bash

I am writing (what should be) a simple bash script to automate a Illumina sequence quality check. I have a problem first with placing only the file names in a temporary text file `ls ${raw_sequences_dir}/*.fastq > ${raw_sequences_dir}/tmp_file_names.txt`. In this case it saves the path and the file name. I tried bypassing this by using this path and file name in the fastqc part of the code but now for each file I am getting weird errors as if bash is trying to run each line in the fastq file instead of performing the fastqc.

Here is an example of the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
##Variables##
#Project code/name/reference
reference="test"
#Setting current directory
current_dir=`pwd`
#Setting output directory
output_dir=${current_dir}/${reference}_output
mkdir -m gu=wrx,o=rx ${output_dir}
#Setting quality output folder
quality_output_dir=${output_dir}/fastqc_results
mkdir -m gu=wrx,o=rx ${quality_output_dir}
#Setting directory to raw sequencing files
raw_sequences_dir=${current_dir}/1604_Sequence_data_raw
#Saving relevant file names to text file for reference
ls ${raw_sequences_dir}/*.fastq > ${raw_sequences_dir}/tmp_file_names.txt

echo "################SELECTED FILE NAMES#####################"

while read file; do
echo ${file}
done < ${raw_sequences_dir}/tmp_file_names.txt

#Setting directory to reference files
ref_files_dir=${current_dir}/Reference_Files

echo "#################Starting quality check...#######################"

###Perform Quality Checks###
while read file; do 
fastqc \ 
${file} \
-o ${quality_output_dir}
done < ${raw_sequences_dir}/tmp_file_names.txt
```

Here is the error from running this script:

```
Skipping ' ' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
/home/path/R_L001_R1_001.fastq: line 1: @M03998:22:000000000-BPN5F:1:1101:15038:1632: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R1_001.fastq: line 2: TCTCGGAACAGAACTTTTAAAGCCGGATCCCGGTTATTCTTTTTTTCTTCTCTCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCTTTTTTCCTCTTTCCCTTTCTCCCTCTTTTTTTCTTCTTTTCCTTTTTTCCTCCTTCCTTTTTTTTCTTTTTCTTTCCTTCCTCCCTTCCCCTTTTTCTCTTTTCTCTTTTTTTTTTCTTTCTCTTTTTCTCTTCTCCTCTCCCCCCTCTCTCTCCCCTTTCTCTTTTTCCTTCTTCTTCTTTCTTTTTTTTTCTCTTCCTCTTCTTCTCTTCCTCTTCTTCCTTCT: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R1_001.fastq: line 3: +: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R1_001.fastq: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/home/path/R_L001_R1_001.fastq: line 4: `@BCC99:7FC@@8FFGGG<,,,;C+++8@@6,+++,;66,,6,,7+,,,,;,,,9,6,666@@+7++8+++6,,<,55+,,,,,55,,5,,,,5,,,,,,55,,++,33,3,33,3,,,,,+,,,3,3,3,,,,,,*3*,,,,,,,22,,,,,,222,*22,2,,,,4,,+1+1++1+++4+1++/***/+++20+*22*0***********)*)*.).)))))**/*))0)())/-)-)-),))-.)))-))-))))))))((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'
Skipping ' ' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 1: @M03998:22:000000000-BPN5F:1:1101:15038:1632: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 2: CTTCATTATAGTTATTACATTCAATTTTTATTTTCTTTCGGTATGCTTTTCCTTCTTTCCTCTCTCCCTCTCTCTTATCATTTCTTTTCTTTCCTTTTCCCCTCTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTCTCCCTTTCTTTCTTTTTTTTTTCTTTTTTCCTTCTTCCCCTCTTCCTCCTTTTCTCTTTCTTTTCCTTTCCTCTCTCTTTTTCTCTTCTTCCCCTCCCCCCCCTCCTCTTTCTCTTCTTCTTCTTTCTTCCCCCTCCCTCTCCTCTCCTTTCTTCTTTCCCCTTTTCTCTTCCTCCTCCC: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 3: +: command not found
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 4: `-8@@,<<,<,,<,,<;,6,<@@,,<,;,;,,<6,,,,66,+8,,,,<;@@66,;6;@C66,6,;,6,;66;6@C,,,,;,,,,<;;@@,,,,95,,,5,,5,,,,,5,5,,,,,6+,,,94,,,4,4,,,,,,,4,,+4++44,4,,4+,,,,,,6,,,,,+,,,,,,,1,7,,,,,3363333+2+++++++2*++0++++*+1++++1++*00**0))))))((((***********/******)))))(((((((((((()()(()))))))))))))((()))))))))))((((('
/home/path/R_L001_R2_001.fastq: line 873604: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `,')
```

When I run the fastqc and specifically mention the file name the fastqc works. I think white space is causing an issue somewhere but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Any help and suggestions will be welcome!

Comment: Does your current directory path contain any whitespace? If it's the case, you will have to quote many variable substitutions in your script

Comment: I checked that and no I could not find any white space

Comment: There is a space after `fastqc \ ` in your script, which changes the meaning of that escape in an unfortunate way. Rather than treating the next line as a continuation, it passes a space as an argument to `fastqc`, and then treats the next line(s) as a completely separate command, which is what's causing it to try to run the contents of your fastq files. (See ["Safe Bash line continuation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910536/safe-bash-line-continuation).)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yap, that was the problem. Can't believe that it slipped through...